# My Z97 GAMING 5 doesn't support 1000mbits?

Tags: networking, motherboard, download, network-adapter

My provider gives me a download speed of 300mbits. I am able to get this speed on my laptop. On my PC however it starts with 300 and lowers to 150/145.

I decided to call my provider and they told me to go to the TCP/IPV4 configuration of my network adapter. In the advanced tab > Speed & Duplex property I found the options:

```
10 Mbps Full Duplex
10 Mbps Half Duplex
100 Mbps Full Duplex
100 Mbps Half Duplex
```

The option 1000 Mbps is not available while my motherboard clearly says it supports 1000 mbits. How can I fix this?

Comment: According to https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z97-GAMING-5.html#hero-specification the motherboard has a "Killer E2205 Gigabit LAN controller". Have you got the latest drivers for the LAN adaptor installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your network card, not (only) on your motherboard.

Verify that your network card model supports it; and then you can try to upgrade the (network card) driver to the newest version.

Comment: But isn't the network card of Z97 Gaming 5 onboard?

Comment: Can be, I don't know. But it still has a model. And then, try the driver update.

Comment: @Tetsujin , if it works on his laptop, everything from the cable and router onwards is already verified.

Comment: I did update the driver and restarted my computer it didn't change anything. Speedtest still shows the same result and 1000mbits option is still not available

Comment: From here I chose the onboard LAN Driver https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z97-GAMING-5.html#down-driver&Win10 64

Comment: I just noticed the previous one was the .inf file.. I am trying the one in the link now.

Comment: I have updated my driver, the option is still not available in the Speed & Duplex property. But I'm guessing that has nothing to do with it since I am able to get a download speed of 300 mbits now. Thank you.